# Bi-directional OneToMany error: why does Hibernate think I am using a composite key?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, composite, one-to-many

I am getting this infamous error:

> Foreign key (FK69848D5097EB6FB4:DOCUMENT_HISTORY [VOTERDOC_ID])) must
>   have same number of columns as the referenced primary key
>   (VOTER_DOCUMENT [VOTER_ID,ID])

But I am not using a composite key. I've confirmed that in the database, the PK for both tables involved is the id field, which is VARCHAR. And here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Table(name = "VOTER_DOCUMENT")
public class VoterDocument {

  @Id
  @Column(length = 45, name = "ID")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "DOCTYPE_ID", nullable = false)
  private DocumentType documentType;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "VOTER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
  private Voter voter;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "voterDocument", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private final List<DocumentHistory> history =
    new ArrayList<DocumentHistory>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "voterDocument", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private final List<VoterFile> files = new ArrayList<VoterFile>();


@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT_HISTORY")
public class DocumentHistory {

  @Id
  @Column(length = 45, name = "ID")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "VOTERDOC_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
  private VoterDocument voterDocument;
```

It seems to be a simple OneToMany mapping, but it's not working. But it's not working in the strangest way, telling me that VoterDocument has a composite primary key, which is not the case.

What could be the problem?

****UPDATED**: I edited my original post to include the whole class, except for getters and setters (which have no markup or Annotations).

Mysteriously enough, the problem seems to have disappeared. I simply commented out the Annotations (in this class and in others), and the errors disappeared. Then I un-commented the comments, and it works!

I think there is some general funkiness going on here, not sure why.

Another error has popped up now, equally absurd. With a simple table:

```
  @Entity
  @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
  @Table(name = "ACTIVE_ELECTION")
  public class ActiveElectionForCounty {

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTY_ID")
  private County county;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ELECTION_EVENT_ID")
  private ElectionEvent electionEvent;
```

This table's PK is the `COUNTY_ID` field from the County table. And the error I am getting is:

> MappingException: composite-id class must implement Serializable:
>   ActiveElectionForCounty

Again with the composite key! But the table doesn't have a composite key! Nor did the last one! Its PK is the County FK. I don't see why Hibernate is complaining. Unfortunately, this time simply commenting and un-commenting the Annotations doesn't fix anything, which is normal of course.

Comment: Show us the exact and complete code of VoterDocument.

Comment: Don't ask several "funky" questions in one. The question will be closed as "not a real question". When the "error disappeared", you most probably had a compilation problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I saw them as related issues, since both problems had to do with non-existent composite ids.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this works but ...

I made my class implement Serializable, added a generated private static final long serialVersionUID, and now  it works.

Still don't understand why .. or why Hibernate thinks I am using a composite key ...